# Data Validation check in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop. I want to know: if we ingest the data how the data validation check is done.

1.Does it contain any corrupted data or not?
2.Does it contain NULL values?
3.Does it contain any duplicate values?
4.How to restrict same file should not be loaded in the same table?

If you know any other data validation check is done other than this, please tell me..

Comment: hi you can not have any such constrains like RDMS..

Answer (score 0):

Its a free world.... No validations, hive can have duplicates, null, corrupt (business wise) etc....